# Crawljax - Require jars file for dynamic webpage crawling

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the javascript webpages(content present within IFrame html tag) using Crawljax. I have added slf4j, crawljax 2.1 and Guava 18.0 jar to the application.

**Error Message displayed in popup:**

```
cannot find symbol 
import com.crawljax.core.configuration.CrawljaxConfiguration.CrawljaxConfigurationBuild‌​er; 
symbol: class CrawljaxConfigurationBuilder 
location: class CrawljaxConfiguration.
```

**Code:**

```
import com.crawljax.core.CrawlerContext;
import com.crawljax.core.CrawljaxRunner;
import com.crawljax.core.configuration.CrawljaxConfiguration;
import com.crawljax.core.configuration.CrawljaxConfiguration.CrawljaxConfigurationBuilder;
import com.crawljax.core.plugin.OnNewStatePlugin;
import com.crawljax.core.state.StateVertex;

public class CrawljaxExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CrawljaxConfigurationBuilder builder
                = CrawljaxConfiguration.builderFor("http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/wpf/default.htm#!documents/overview.htm");
        builder.addPlugin(new OnNewStatePlugin() {

            @Override
            public void onNewState(CrawlerContext context, StateVertex newState) {
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Our example plugin";
            }
        });
        CrawljaxRunner crawljax = new CrawljaxRunner(builder.build());
        crawljax.call();
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CrawljaxConfigurationBuilder
  location: class com.crawljax.core.configuration.CrawljaxConfiguration
    at crawljaxexamples.CrawljaxExamples.<clinit>(CrawljaxExamples.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Same code could be found in below Link,

https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/crawljax/examples/PluginExample.java

Can someone please tell what are jars files required to run this program? Or is there any settings to be changed in IDE?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have not added dependencies. Paste your exception and code

Comment: @Kumar, Added code and exception details;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using old version of crawljax.

Download latest version [crawljax-cli-3.5.1.zip](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/releases)

Add all jars from lib folder and crawljax-cli-3.5.1.jar from the main folder as lib path.

Tested and now it works well.

Comment: We are using the latest version(3.5.1) only; Also added all the jar files;

Comment: It seems your lib path referring the old jars. Remove all the libraries and add the new from the latest package.

Comment: Yes.. lib path referring the old jars.i have another doubt.. Why crawljax take more time for single website crawling?

Comment: You have to refer the crawljax website for more.

Comment: @Bass .. I did the same; Removed all jars and added reference once again from within my application's lib folder; Still not working :(